# writing special characters to output port in scheme (compiler design)

Tags: assembly, compilation, compiler-construction, scheme, 64-bit

I have a homework assignment to create a compiler in chez scheme for chez scheme (to x64 assembly).
My technique so far has been to create a giant string, which I then display on a file. For example lets say my output assembly program is stored in the variable 'str' - what I do to write it to a file is:

```
(define out (open-output-port "file-name"))  
(display str out)
```

My string is separated by \n's, which mark the end of each line. For example:   part of a final 'str' could look like this:

```
"mov rax, rdx\n  
LoopStart:\n  
cmp rdx,0\n"
```

and so on... (assembly code)
This is achieved by using (many) calls to string-append for each line of code in scheme.
It has been working fine until I realized that i can't output "special" characters to the assembly file - for instance \n - which gets interpreted as a new line in the final file, even though I would like to be able to produce that combination of characters in my final assembly. Same goes for \t, #\newline and any other special character that the display function will "consume".
I saw that there is another scheme function which doesn't "consume" these special characters - write.
The problem with write is that, for instance:

```
(write out "blablalba \n\n blabla")
```

will produce the following text in the file "out": "blabla \n\n blabla"
 (including the parentheses!!!)
I want to find a way to be able to write strings WITHOUT the parentheses but also without "consuming" the special characters.
Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks, Elad

~~~~~~~~~~~~~EDIT~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Ok, first of all thanks for the responses.
I'll try to be more precise with my question though,
What I wanted is to be able to compile this line of code for example:

```
    (char? "\n")
```

My compiler is supposed to mimic Chez scheme (I'm not using racket!) and of course Chez returns #f for this.
In MY compiler though, I first scan the code for any constants - and I find this string of course, but because of the display function the outputted code will have a line break instead of the string literal '\n'.
So as suggested, I think that all I need to do is to find a way to replace the '\' character with '\\' in string literals (because NASM syntax really shouldn't contain these special characters except in string literals).
Is there an easy way to go about this? I could use string->list and and then search for these special cases (I think there are about 5 - \n,\r,\t, can't think of any more right now)
anyway, I will try to write it and I will post here afterwards. Thanks

~~~~~~~~~~~~SECOND EDIT~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~`
ok now I understand that I need to do something else,
I need to be able to turn this string:

```
    "abc\nabc\n\tabc"
```

to this:

```
    "'abc',10,'abc',10,9,'abc'"
```

this is because I actually do have a "db" prefix in front of this, and this is how your'e supposed to define this string literal in assembly.

how to do this in scheme?

Comment: I really didn't understand so much, but why don't you utilize a kind of Translation Table to understand that ASCII "\n" is really 0xA, 0xD ?

Comment: don't really understand how this can help me, my goal is to be able to write valid assembly into a file. display won't let me include character combinations such as \n,\t in my final output - because it will literally create a tab or a new line, in which I'm not interested. write will not do this but will wrap any string I give it in parentheses, which I'm also not interested in.

Comment: Are you saying you want your assembly file to contain a literal backslash followed by an n? Why? That's not valid assembly syntax (except inside string constants, but that doesn't seem to be what you're asking about).

Comment: I really didn't understand what you really want...

Comment: @erap129 If you do `(display "\\n")` you get the output `"\n` and no linefeed. Thus you need to replace ``\`` with ``\\`` and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things that need to be cleared up here:

`"\n"` is a string of length 1 that contains a newline. `"\\n"` is a string of length 2 that contains a backslash and an n. `display` doesn't convert anything inside a string, it only prints what's inside the string. So if you have a string containing a backslash and an n, `display` will print that.

When you have a file containing a backslash and an n and you read that file into a string, you'll get the string `"\\n"`, not the string `"\n"`. The latter is what you'd get if the file contained an actual newline.

So if you have a file with the contents `"abc\n"` and you want to turn that into `db 'abc\n'`, you don't have to do anything with the `\n`. Once you've read the file into a string, you'll have the string `"\"abc\\n\""` (which contains a quote, the letters abc, a backslash, an n and another quote). Then you replace the double quotes with single quotes and add a `db` in front and you'll get `"db 'abc\\n'"`. You print that and you'll get `db 'abc\n'` and that's that.

Assuming your target syntax is nasm, that's it. `db 'abc\n'` is valid nasm syntax and will do what you want. `db 'abc', 10` is also valid syntax and does the same thing, but as long as your input syntax only contains escape sequences supported by nasm, there should be no need to translate them to bytes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you want to be able to emit a string that contains, for instance, \n. For instance, to create a text file that contains the string

abc\ndef

Is that right?

If so, then the answer is easy: simply "display" a string containing the characters that you want. In fact, I believe that you're slightly misunderstanding your program; the challenge isn't in getting display to do what you want, but in specifying the string that you want to output.

Let's begin with code:

```
#lang racket

(define str "abc\\ndef")

(define out (open-output-file "/tmp/file-name"))  
(display str out)
```

You should find that the output file contains eight characters: an 'a', a 'b', a 'c', a backslash, an 'n', a 'd', an 'e', and an 'f'.

Here's the (maybe) surprising thing: the string in the file is exactly the same string defined by str. One way to see this is to check the string-length, or to map the string to a list:

```
(string-length str) ;; -> 8
(string->list str) ;; -> '(#\a #\b #\c #\\ #\n #\d #\e #\f)
```

So in fact, your real challenge doesn't have anything to do with 'display', which simply dumps the characters to the port; your problem is in constructing the strings in the first case, which can be done in a number of different ways. You can use quoting characters, as I did in this example, or you can use the `string` function, which turns a list of characters into a string, or you can use "here-strings"... or any number of other techniques.

Comment: I don't think this solves the OP's real problem (though I'm pretty sure this *is* what OP asked for). I think the OP's real problem is that he for some reason thinks that assembly files should contain backslash-n at the end of each line to be valid, when, in fact, that would make them invalid. I think what OP really wants is exactly what his code is doing right now - he just doesn't realize that.

Comment: thanks, this is definitely the right direction. Though now my problem is more focused (second edit of original post)

Answer (score 0):

You never need a literal `\` or `"` character in the x86 Intel syntax you're using, which makes it easy to wrap it in a double-quoted string without having to use `\\` escapes to get a literal `\` in the asm.

---

In fact, YASM doesn't even support character literals with C-style escape processing, so you only need `\` as part of a character constant that has a literal `\`.  NASM does support C-style escapes inside backquotes, but either way you can always use numeric constants instead.

e.g. instead of

```
push  `abc\n`        ; NASM syntax for a numeric constant that will have the ASCII codes for  a, b, c, \n in that order in memory
mov   rsi, rsp   ; buf
mov   eax, 1     ; sys_write
mov   edi, 1     ; stdout
mov   edx, 4     ; length
syscall          ; x86-64 Linux sys_write(1, "abc\n", 4)
...
```

you can emit the same machine-code bytes with

```
; YASM syntax, or NASM without any C-style escapes
push   ('abc' <<8) | 0xa     ; 0xa = ASCII code for newline
...
```

So it's awkard in that case to mix character literals with numeric literals, instead of just using `push 0x0a636261`  (x86 is little-endian).

It's much simpler as arguments to a `db` pseudo-instruction:

```
    lea   rdi, [rel hello_string]
    call  printf        ; puts would be more efficient, but for example purposes I don't want a function that adds a newline on its own.
    ...

section .rodata
  hello_string: db 'Hello World!', 0xa, 0   ; null-terminated string
  ; instead of 'Hello World!\n\0'
```

Multi-byte quoted strings work as multiple arguments to `db`.  I assume the flavour of Intel syntax you're using inside this double-quoted string in scheme is similar enough to those.

Everything I said above applies also to GNU `as`: you can use `.byte` as needed after `.ascii`, or use numeric constants for immediates.